# Vector Derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know that 
 $\nabla_x [\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{a}$
 $\nabla_x [\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{a}] = \mathbf{a}$

but what about $\nabla_x [\mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{a}]$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ $x,a \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) (index notation) which a lot of physicists love is very handy here:
$\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$
The index notation of $\b{y}\b{x}^T\b{a}$ is
$$
\b{y}\b{x}^T\b{a} = y_i x_j a_j = k_i
$$
for repeating indices got canceled, and result index follows $\b{y}$'s hence $\b{k} = k_i\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Taking derivative with respect to $\b{x}$ is:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \b{x}}\b{y}\b{x}^T\b{a} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_m}(y_i x_j a_j) = (y_i x_j a_j)_{,m} = y_i (x_j)_{,m} a_j = y_i \frac{\partial x_j }{\partial x_m} a_j = y_i \delta_{jm}a_j
$$
where $\delta_{jm}$ is the Kronecker delta:
$$
\delta_{jm}=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad\text{if } j=m
\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \b{x}}\b{y}\b{x}^T\b{a} = y_i a_m =d_{im} = \b{y}\b{a}^T
$$
for $d_{im}$ is a matrix has $y_i a_m$ at $i$-th row, $m$-th column.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(x) = y x^T a$. Then $\phi(x+h) = y x^T a + y h^T a$, from which it follows that $D \phi(x)(h) = y h^T a = y a^T h$. Hence we have $D\phi(x) = y a^T$.